# How do I reverse sort natural in Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a capped collection and I know I need to issue:

```
find().sort({$natural:-1})
```

to sort by most recent first. But how do I do this in Morphia?

```
query.order("-$natural"); // doesn't work
```

Comment: Are you using the latest snapshot? That seems to be the proper syntax.

Comment: Hmm.. is that Morphia 0.99.1? Seems to be 6 months old :(

Comment: Yeah, it's old but it's better than stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: disable validation just after creating the query object and everything functions as expected.